# Make scrollbar visible in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, mobile-browser

when I have a web page with a scrollable content. With css property "overflow:auto" or "overflow:visible" the scrollbar is visible on desktop browsers, but when I open the page on mobile browsers the scrollbar appears only when I try to scroll. 
Is there a way to make the scrollbar always visible on mobile devices? I have tried some JQuery libraries but none of them have worked.

The html code is trivial, I have a scrollable div with an IFrame inside:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <iframe id="frameContent" src="mysite" scrollable="yes"></iframe>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#wrapper{
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}

#frameContent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Try adding the below to your CSS, note that this is [webkit](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790) [specific](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=547260):

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/2nT38/)

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your JSFiddle does not have the expected behaviour...the scrollbar is not visible

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: ...but the css works with my html page...question solved! Thanks!

Comment: what about the non-webkit browsers?

Comment: You'll need to look into a JS solution, e.g. http://davidwalsh.name/iphone-scrollbars (untested)

Comment: This solution doesn't work on Chrome on iOS8. Any other ideas?

Comment: Doesn't seem to behave on iOS Safari.

Comment: Still works on Android even though it does not use webkit anymore as a render engine!

Comment: what if I want to display the default scrollbar and not this styling

Answer (score 17):

```
  /* !important is needed sometimes */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px !important;
 }

 /* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) !important;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
   border-radius: 10px !important;
 }

 /* Handle */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
   border-radius: 10px !important;
   background: #41617D !important; 
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important; 

 }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
   background: #41617D !important; 
 }
```

Add this css code - It will change the style of scrollbar in mobile devices only

Comment: Works on android but not iOS mobile. Maybe because im using safari.

Comment: Even though it is also working on safari responsive design mode on my mac. Very strange.

Comment: Not behaving on iOS Safari.

Comment: Anyone tested it on Safari with `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: Auto;` inside the `::-webkit-scrollbar` element?

Answer (score 6):

For issues with Safari, IOS browsers,

Setting

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto

along with mentioned CSS above in other ::-webkit-scrollbar solutions here, works well

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem believe me any style won't do anything to make the scrollbar visible always on mobile what I did was use simplebar library very easy to use just link the CSS and JS files and add data-simplebar attr in the parent remove the overflow scroll and just make sure that the parent is actually overflowing all check here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kradT.jpg)