# Always show scrollbars in iPhone/Android

Tags: html, css, iphone, scrollbar

Is there a way to keep the scrollbars always visible in mobile browser. By default a scrollable page get its scroll visible only when a touch/swipe is happening. How can I make the scrollbars always visible ?

Comment: Many mobile browsers don't show scrollbars at all, while some show them only while scrolling. So no matter what you put in your CSS,thing you want to achieve might be impossible.

Comment: @Richa are you sure. Is there any documentation for that. I can simply show that to client and stop trying the impossible

Comment: Do you want it for all mobile browser only in mobile devices?? For PC browser you can do `html {overflow-y:scroll;}`

Comment: @Richa, I need it for mobile.. There is a table and it will not show scrollbar for Large screen. The same will be scrollable in medium/small screens. Everything is perfect but I want to show the scroller always

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907777/make-scrollbar-visible-in-mobile-browsers

Answer (score 22):

Try this one on your css styles

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;  
    background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Comment: Or with this code 

    html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    }

Should be works

Comment: This works in Android devices browsers, not in iPhone safari or iPhone chrome.

Comment: setting -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto along with other styles above, works in safari, iphone browsers

Comment: Does not work on iOS Chrome or Safari