# Always show scrollbar in Bootstrap table-responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using .table-responsive class to make my Bootstrap tables responsive and it's working fine but the user doesn't have any indicator that the table is horizontally scrollable!

How can I make the horizontal scrollbar always displayed, not only after the user actually starts scrolling.

**Edit**

The solution mentioned here almost works: [Always show scrollbars in iPhone/Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684620/always-show-scrollbars-in-iphone-android):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;  
    background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Its problem is showing the scrollbars everywhere, not just to .table-responsive class. How I can restrict it?

Comment: Are you seeing this on OS X?

Comment: @alex OS X and Android.

Comment: it's by design, read https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12877 . Guess your easier way is to add a small message like "scroll table" or whatever

Comment: Try *overflow-x:scroll*

Comment: create a css rule, and add your css code above to that rule eg
.scroll-msg ::-webkit-scrollbar...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry for being 5 years late, but you must add .table-responsive before the pseudo-element, like this:

```
.table-responsive::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.table-responsive::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}

.table-responsive::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;
}

.table-responsive::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

.table-responsive::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;  
    background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Comment: You are just in time.

Comment: Thanks,  However I'll need to rethink the "auto-load" when user scrolls to the bottom of table, else this scrollbar is not easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can enclose your table with:

```
<div style="overflow-x:scroll;">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add `overflow-x:scroll` to the <768 breakpoint, it will always show the scrollbar below 768px. But as a caveat, it will also show when there is nothing to scroll (i.e. if the table is narrower than 768px)...

```
@media(max-width:767px){
  .table-responsive{overflow-x:scroll;}
}
```

Comment: I tried this in both Firefox and Chrome, to no effect.  The rule is not being overridden.  What else could it be?

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you could do is to use a pseudo element.

```
.<classname>:before {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    content: "Swipe left to read more";
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
}
```