# Force horizontal scroll bar when using default android browser

Tags: android, jquery, css, cross-browser

I have a web page I have developed that displays a horizontal scroll bar for a grid when viewed in IE and Chrome.
The scroll bar show when viewed from a desktop and even shows when viewed from Chrome on a mobile android device.
But the scroll bar does not appear on the default "internet" browser on a mobile android device.
Anyone know how to make it show?

I added overflow-x:scroll; overflow:scroll;
I also added WebKit http://www.quora.com/How-do-you-force-the-horizontal-scroll-bar-to-show-in-Safari-5 which makes it work on Chrome on the android mobile.

The solution can be jquery, css, or other. I just need a solution.

Comment: What about using iscroll : https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/ ? I think it can handle it without hassle.

Comment: Have a look at this answer:
<http://stackoverflow.com/q/22907777/4350275>

Comment: @PrerakSola Thanks for the link. It seems all I was missing was the -WebKit-scrollbar:horizontal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO problem.... Your welcome... :)

Final output

```
::-WebKit-scrollbar {
    -WebKit-appearance: none;
}

::-WebKit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -WebKit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 5px;
}
```