# Iframe pdf scroll not visible in IOS devices (iPhone , iPad)

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, cross-browser

I was trying this code below, it's working in all browsers include the IE browser, but the problem scrollbar was hidden in IPad and iPhone Devices & added CSS also for browser-specific still no luck !!!

Does anyone help how to solve this issue?

```
<object data="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf">
    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=your_url_to_pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for scrollbars to be hidden on mobile devices. But you can force them to appear by overriding the styles of `::-webkit-scrollbar-*` properties.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22907848/7541003) in another Stack Overflow thread provides an example:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;  
    background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```