# How to make ScrollBar always visible in mobile? (CSS) (iPhone)

Tags: css, scroll, safari, scrollbar

I made a div that has a scroll function. The scroll bars appear on my desktop browsers (chrome, safari, firefox) but when it comes to mobile, the scrollbar isn't visible. (Scroll works though)

How can I make this visible all the time?

```
  .scroll_log {
    overflow-y:auto;
    max-height:350px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
  }
  .scroll_log::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 12px !important;
  }
  .scroll_log::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    background: #41617D !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
  }

  .scroll_log::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
  }
  .scroll_log::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: #41617D !important;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making the main scrollbar always visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202425/making-the-main-scrollbar-always-visible)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907777/make-scrollbar-visible-in-mobile-browsers
did you try this?

Comment: Yes I tried that

Comment: Same, it does not work for Iphone and Ipad

Comment: Any updates/solutions to this? I am facing the same issue.