# Overflow-x scrollbars aren't visible on Chrome until I select and drag on content?

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design, user-experience

I need to make a data grid that works at different screen sizes. A common approach is just to wrap the grid element in a div with `overflow-x: auto`.

https://codepen.io/adsfdsfhdsafkhdsafjkdhafskjds/pen/eYWEoya

```
<div class='page'>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-inner">
      <div>Heading1</div>
      <div>Heading2</div>
      <div>Heading3</div>
      <div>Heading4</div>
      
      <div>Here is come content 1</div>
      <div>Here is come content 2</div>
      <div>Here is come content 3</div>
      <div>Here is come content 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
.page {
  background: grey;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.grid {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.grid-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.grid-inner div {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Technically this works but I have a UX concern. On Chrome the scrollbars arn't initially visible so a user might not know there is scrollable content which they can't see:

[image]

The only way to scroll on desktop Chrome is to click on the content and drag to the right. At that point the scrollbars appear although content is also highlighted which isnt ideal:

[image]

Is it possible to make the scrollbars be permanently visible when the content is wider than it's `overflow: auto` container and is therefore scrollable? Or is there a totally different approach that is common in this scenario?

Comment: We're talking about Chrome on a mobile device, right? Because on desktop, the scrollbar is always visible. In that case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907777/make-scrollbar-visible-in-mobile-browsers might work!

Comment: @ConstantinGroß No im talking about desktop Chrome. The first screenshot (without scrollbars) was taken on my MacBook running desktop Chrome v91.

Comment: Oh, ok, so that's OS-dependent then, interesting! Apparently, the solution I linked doesn't work on iOS devices, either... =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option for you:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/wvdrzMe

It should work well on OS X Chrome and Safari and it's easy enough to style the slider the way you want.

[image]

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 8px;
        background-color:#aaa;
    }

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    }
```

Comment: Looks good. What is the purpose of -webkit-appearance: none in this context?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Evanss, there's no reason to include -webkit-appearance: none in this example.

Comment: Sadly this doenst work on iOS mobile Chrome or Safari

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Evanss, same for me. According to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670065, as of iOS 14 custom scrollbars are no longer supported in iOS